# hide download link of ios install app by php

Tags: php, ios, onclick

Solved.

i have a link for install ios app that work in safari.

```
<a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://acqshop.com/manifest/category/Farsi/ashpazi.plist"></a>
```

now i want to hide link from users .but i'am not sure how to do this. 
i used onclick for link :

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:install();" target="Farsi/ashpazi.plist"></a>

function install() {
if (!isMobile()) {
    alert('you can download from ios devices');
    return;
}
var post_link = $(this).attr("target");
url = 'install.php?name='+post_link;
window.location.href = url;
}
```

and in install.php :

```
<?php
$name = $_GET['name'];      
$path = 'itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://acqshop.com/manifest/category/'.$name;
$mm_type="application/octet-stream"; 
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Type: " . $mm_type);
header("Content-Length: " .(string)(filesize($path)) );
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($path).'"');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\n");
readfile($path); // outputs the content of the file
exit();
?>
```

but it not work. what's my wrong.
you can see an example for onclick function to download ios app in this site:     
ipa.othman.tv/ipa/vi2.php 
but i can't understant what's the functions in installvi2.php
(please see the page source)
thanks.

thanks to @Shynggys
i changed install.php to :

```
<?php
$name = $_GET['name'];      
$path = 'itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://acqshop.com/manifest/category/'.$name;
$mm_type="application/octet-stream"; 
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header('Location:' .$path); 
?>
```

Comment: you can see an example for onclick function to download ios app in this site : http://ipa.othman.tv/ipa/vi2.php , but i can't understant what's the functions in installvi2.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use absolute URL, not relative, and return 'false' from function 'install', it should look something like this:

```
function install() {
if (!isMobile()) {
    alert('you can download from ios devices');
    return;
}
var post_link = $(this).attr("target");
url = 'http://MyWebSite.kz/install.php?name='+post_link;
window.location.href = url;
return false;
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: thanks.but noting changed, my problem is functions in install.php,

Comment: try just to redirect a user from install.php to your link